# ASP.net Core 1.0 Mapping property on ApplicationUser returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

First, I adopted a project due to a developer jumping ship, so not only is this my first experience with .net core, but I'm having to digest a large code-base that I didn't write.

I need to know where to look to resolve an issue. I have a view that renders in a table a list of records.

Here are the relevant classes accessed:

```
[Table("AccountDetails")]
public class AccountDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FileUpload> Files { get; set; }

}
```

The problem is occurring in the `Files` property.

```
[Table("FileUploads")]
public class FileUpload
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the method that returns this list:

```
var files = _form.AccountDetail.Files.Select(q => new FileModel
  {
    FileName = q.FileName,
    FileId = q.Id,
    EffectiveDate = q.CreatedOn.ToString("d"),
    FormId = _form.Id,
    UploadedBy = $"{ q.CreatedBy.FirstName } { q.CreatedBy.LastName }"
  }).ToList();
```

`ApplicationUser` extends `IdentityUser`. `UploadedBy` is the problem which is mapped to ApplicationUser.

With an admin role, this never fails and it properly maps to the `ApplicationUser` so `CreatedBy` is never `null`.

However, under a different user account which is not an admin role anything not created by that user returns null, which triggers an object reference error.

Now I know the issue deserves a quick response like, "Hey, obviously the user doesn't have the right permissions.", but I need assistance with where to look to solve this.

In this case, `CreatedBy` should never return `null`.

I don't quite know where or how this auto-mapping is occurring.

I found this in snapshot:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Accounting.Entities.FileUpload", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Accounting.Entities.ApplicationUser", "CreatedBy")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CreatedById");


            });
```

`CreatedById` is the column in the actual table that references `AspNetUsers`.

If I go all the way back to the constructor for the controller being called:

```
public FormAccountsController(ApplicationDbContext context,
                           UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                           IMapper mapper,
                           RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) : base(context, userManager, roleManager, mapper)
    {

    }
```

And I look in `ApplicationDbContext context`, I can see `FileUploads` and CreatedBy is null for the record that was not created by this particular user, but from this point on I'm not sure where to look. And again, if I sign in with an admin account, `CreatedBy` is never null.

Comment: Would you show your `MapperConfiguraton` in  the `ConfigureSerevices` please?

Comment: How did you return `_form.AccountDetail.Files`? Check the reason why `CreatedBy` is different for different users.

Comment: @TanvirArjel your comment got me just close enough to drill down into the right direction and find the issue. It was in the `include` logic of the form factory. See my answer. And of course if you have a better explanation compared to my answer then please post and I'll ditch my and accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TanvirArjel for comment to original question, I was able to follow the trail and find the issue. It was in the `include` logic within the form factory.

```
if (user.AccountProfile != null)
        {
            form = _context.Forms.Include(q => q.AccountingDetail)
                .ThenInclude(q => q.Files)


                .ThenInclude(q => q.CreatedBy) // This was missing
                .Single(q => q.Id == formId);


        }
```